# How to automatically calculate the max and min of a chart so that high or low values don't fall out?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to create a chart for BTC price. The app gets the price via api (podatek1). I'm using NodeJS 
What I'm trying to do is that the chart will display the price's movements and scale the data to display it on canvas. The price is given every 5s and that's why I used the splice method to put in the new value and remove the oldest value from the chart. What I can't figure out is how to keep the graph inside the canvas because right now if the price is greater than Zmeja (upper border) the point can't be seen.
How am I supposed to calculate max and min so the point will be seen on the chart? The code needs to calculate max and min automatically. 

Zmeja and Smeja are just values of the upper and lower border of the canvas.

**price chart with preset values**

[image]

**price is greater than the upper border**

[image]

```
var canvas;
var ctx;

canvas = document.getElementById("cv");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "#00c3c3";

var x = new Array();
var y = new Array();

x = [0,40,70,100,150,200,250,300,350,400];
y = [50,20,60,40,80,20,70,60,90];

ctx.beginPath();

for (var i=0; i<canvas.width; i++){

ctx.lineTo(x[i], y[i]);
}

function graf(podatek1){

var Zmeja = parseFloat(podatek1)+25; //8100
var Smeja = parseFloat(podatek1)-25; //8050
var max = 9130;
var min = 9080;
var range = max - min;
var yPx = 200; // število px po y osi
var podatekSkaliran1;

podatekSkaliran1 = ((max - podatek1)/range)*yPx;

y.splice(0, 1);
//y[i] = i++;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
y[9] = podatekSkaliran1;
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.fillText(Zmeja,0,15);
ctx.fillText(Smeja,0,195);

for (var i=0; i<y.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(x[i], y[i]);
}

ctx.stroke();

//var timerVar = setTimeout(zanka, 400);
}

function load() {

ctx.beginPath();

for (var i=0; i<y.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(x[i], y[i]); 
}

ctx.stroke();

//zanka();

}
```

Comment: Please add more information on what you expect your code to do and how it is actually broken. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGs6D.jpg).So instead of writing it on your on, You should use Google charts

```
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2013',  1000,      400],
      ['2014',  1170,      460],
      ['2015',  660,       1120],
      ['2016',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can refer this [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart)

Comment: basically yes but first I need to do it my way. I just don't know how to calculate the max and min automatically so the graph stays inside the canvas, because right now if the new price (which is given every 5s) is greater than Zmeja (upper border) the graph goes off canvas. :(

Comment: So Basically have to maintain a global queue where price remain in the range of canvas(queue size=canvas range) and every 5 seconds when a change came in you pop first one if no space available in queue and refresh the canvas itself which only take the reference of the global queue.